# Best way to share package configuration in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

Let's say I import a node.js package and configure it, for example winston:

```
var log = require('winston');
log.add(log.transports.File, { filename: 'debug.log', level: 'debug'});
```

If I require the same package in another file, I lose the configuration and have to configure it again! What is the best way to configure a package once? For now I have put my configuration into a file called `s_winston.js` which configures the package and then exports it. In my other files I do:

```
log = require('../s_winston.js');
```

Should I do this for all my packages which need configuration? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your configuration inside a `.json` file and require it as usual:

```
var config = require('path/to/config.json'); // or without extension: require('path/to/config');
```

Also if you have so many modules to configure and want to save all in one place, you could save you configuration objects in a js file:

```
module.exports = {
    Module1_config: {
        // Your configuration for module one
    },
    Module2_config: {
        // Your configuration for module two
    }
    // And so on
};
```

then just:

```
var config = require('path/to/config);

module1.config(config.Module1_config);
module2.config(config.Module2_config);
/* ... */
```

Comment: I'm actually doing that already for something else. But I'm not sure how I can apply this technique to configuring my logger as described in the question?

Comment: Saving a configuration inside a .json is a terrible idea. Use json5 or yaml instead. Just saying.

Comment: why using json is a so terrible idea? it's natively supported and it's just data.